# What is the command erepc? Is this malware?

Tags: security, process, malware, administration

I noticed that my system was running slower than normal so I ran a top command. Hogging a ton of my CPU was a process called `erepc` that I can find no information on.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                      
 8826 chris     20   0  125336  23452    540 S  38.2  0.3   2570:04 erepc                                                                                                                                        
31175 user     20   0  237128  13044   5708 S  17.3  0.2  42:16.34 afpd                                                                                                                                         
  966 user2    20   0   33944  10072   9852 S  14.0  0.1 500:25.74 cnid_dbd                                                                                                                                     
31428 root      20   0   11200   2644   2096 S  11.3  0.0   0:01.65 find                                                                                                                                         
 2222 sudo      20   0 1580592 188404  17132 S   9.0  2.3   6639:02 cinnamon                                                                                                                                     
16794 sudo      20   0  237016  12916   5708 S   4.0  0.2   2:51.05 afpd
```

I have killed the process and deleted the user `chris`, who was a user that I created for SMB shares. Is this a normal process, or has some stupid script kiddie done something to my server?

Edit: There is indeed an executable file in the home folder for now deleted user `chris`. It's pretty clear that somebody remote was running some kind of process on my server.

Comment: Are you running Mint on an install that was created in the past month?

Comment: It is Mint, but I believe that it was installed more than a month ago.

Comment: I just verified the MD5 hash as per this site: http://www.zdnet.com/article/has-your-linux-mint-desktop-been-hacked/

Comment: if you are not sure or cutting close to that 1 month time mentioned, and if I were you, I would backup my data and reinstall the system from a clean source, in the light of what happened to Linux Mint website.

Comment: The MD5 signature matches. I can be pretty certain it's not one of the infected installs.

Comment: according to [this site](http://r.virscan.org/report/45ec707e8cd5777b9bdc4b041fdd568c), it is a virus

Comment: What should I do to ensure that my machine is safe? I have no idea what this malware even does. It was also running on a user with limited privileges.

Comment: @ezgoodnight back up your non-executable data. Verify that the backups contain all the necessary data. Wipe the machine. Reinstall. Restore the backups.

Comment: Jesus, that's so much work. I really wish I had been more careful on the front side. I appreciate your response @roaima.